# Invariant Violation: "borderLeft" is not a valid style property

Tags: reactjs, react-native, styled-components

I'm using [styled-components](https://www.styled-components.com/) in a React Native project and I'm trying to set a left border in a text component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const TitleText = (props) => {
  return (
    <Text>{props.text}</Text>
  );
};

const Text = styled.Text`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily};
  color: ${props => props.theme.darkBlue};
  border-left: 1px solid #000;
`;
```

The problem is that after adding `border-left: 1px solid #000`and reload the app, it shows: "Invariant Violation: "borderLeft" is not a valid style property".

How can I add a left border to that component using styled components?

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe it's possible to directly set the border left (or top, right, bottom) style property on components in react native. 
This is likely to be the cause of your error, in that there is no mapping from `border-left` to any equivalent styling property in react native.

Your best best might be to explicitly specify the border property values per side as follows:

```
const Text = styled.Text`
  font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily};
  color: ${props => props.theme.darkBlue};

  /* Note that react native typically requires the same 
     border style to be applied to all sides of a component 
     that supports borders */
  border-style: solid; 

  /* Most components in react native support unique border width and 
     colors on each side of the component */
  border-left-color: #000; 
  border-left-width: 1px;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following changes should solve the issue-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

const TitleText = (props) => {
 return (
  <Text>{props.text}</Text>
 );
};

const Text = styled.Text`
font-family: ${props => props.theme.fontFamily};
color: ${props => props.theme.darkBlue};
border-left-width: 1px;
border-left-style : solid;
border-left-color : #fff
`;
```

Refer following links for available properties -

[Layout Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props)

[StyleSheetGuide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet)

Comment: "border top style is not a valid style property" :(